# Python3 on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, python3.2

How does one install Python3 on cygwin? I tried running the Python install in cygwin with no success.

The version I am looking for is >= 3.1, and I was able to install 2.7 successfully under cygwin (which comes with 2.6 as the default).

By the way, I would like to run Python3 as python3 and not python. I don't want conflicts with the default python binaries that come with cygwin.

Help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of yesterday (Wed 25 July 2012), [Python 3.2.3 is included in the standard Cygwin installer](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-07/msg00553.html). Just run Cygwin's `setup.exe` again (download it from [cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com) again if you need to), and you should be able to select and install it like any other package.

This will still install as `python3`, leaving any existing 2.x install in place, just as before:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.6.8
$ python3 -V
Python 3.2.3
$ ls -l $(which python) $(which python3)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me Domain Users 13 Jun 21 15:12 /usr/bin/python -> python2.6.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me root         14 Jul 26 10:56 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.2m.exe
```

Comment: brilliant!  thanks for keeping the question in mind!

Comment: can't vote up, not enough rep :(

Comment: @ethiopianqubit you should be able to Mark this answer as accepted regardless of your rep, though - just click on the grey tick.

Comment: when I do `which python` in cygwin terminal, it prints `/cygdrive/d/Programs/python/python-3.6.6-amd64/python` (that is it refers to the Windows python). When I do `which python3` in cygwin terminal, it prints `/usr/bin/python3` (this one is the one which I installed through cygwin setup). Do I need to fix this?

Comment: @Mahesha999 I suspect you'll get a better response and more visibility if you ask your question as a new question, rather than here.

Comment: yeah may be but I am equally anxious that people may downvote it

Comment: @Mahesha999 If you're clear about what you're asking, why you're asking, and what research you've already done, I find people very rarely downvote; IME downvoting questions tends to only be for the most egregiously unclear ones, not least because it costs people points to downvote.

Comment: super brilliant answer

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using [Cygwin Ports](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/), a bunch of programs that have been ported to Cygwin, but aren't ready for general release.

From that page:

> 1. Use the latest Cygwin [setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe) (at least version 2.738).
> 2. Launch setup.exe with the -K flag, e.g.:
>
>    ```
>      cygstart -- /path/to/setup.exe -K http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg
>    ```
> 3. On Choose Installation Type page, select "Install from Internet".
> 4. On Choose Download Site(s) page, select a distro mirror, then enter ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports in the User URL field and press Add (making sure that both are highlighted).
>
>    - Mirrors are available by instead entering http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports as the User URL.
>    - Alternatively, you can use a sourceware mirror, but if you do, you must use one hosted on a different server than your selected distro mirror.
> 5. Proceed with package selection and installation, making sure to install any indicated dependencies.

Note that the two links provided didn't work for me; I'd expect FTP not to work as it's restricted by my firewall, but I think the alternative Sourceforge link is duff, and should be http://sourceforge.net/projects/cygwin-ports/files/. Using that URL worked fine for me.

From there, you should be able to select to install the python3 package. It's currently giving version 3.1.5rc1-1.

It does install as `python3`, leaving my existing python install as v2.6.8:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.6.8
$ python3 -V
Python 3.1.5rc1
$ ls -l $(which python) $(which python3)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me root         13 Jun 12 13:43 /usr/bin/python -> python2.6.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me Domain Users 13 Jun 19 10:51 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.1.exe
```